# How to display or break a long equation properly?

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I would like to ask about writing equation for this double columns' format. 
My equation is a bit long for this format so the equation numbering moves to the bottom as in the first case. 
Is this normal to keep it like that?
I also tried to fix it by using split to break the equation but this doesn't look good to me. 
Please let me know a standard or better way to do it as I don't have experience on this.
[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:label1}
\frac{x_n}{y_{HADL}} =
\frac{1}{-[k_3 N   +p_3 (1-N)]  -q_2 [k_2 N  + p_2 (1-N)] }
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:label2}
\begin{split}
\frac{x_n}{y_{HADL}} &=\\
&\frac{1}{-[k_3 N   +p_3 (1-N)]  -q_2 [k_2 N  + p_2 (1-N)] }
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some shortening and better typesetting would be to write y_\text{HADL} instead of  y_{HADL}. You could also factorise the minus sign  and even put it on the numerator.

Comment: @Jhor It's "undocumented behavior" that `_\text{...}` without another brace group works though. Might break any time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. EDIT: I just checked but it doesn't look good to me.

Comment: @user202729. You're right, of course. But I did that for hundreds of equations in several document and classes without any problem..

Comment: @Jhor -- If it always worked, you were lucky, or never varied your use, never using it in a context where it might be fragile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixing Computer Modern math with Times is really bad. If you load `newtx` (or `mathptmx`, if you want to be old-fashioned), the math will be compatible.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\usepackage{newtx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:label1}
\frac{y^{}_{\mathrm{HADL}}}{x_n}=
-[k_3 N   +p_3 (1-N)]  -q_2 [k_2 N  + p_2 (1-N)]
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:label2}
\frac{x_n}{y^{}_{\mathrm{HADL}}} =
\frac{1}{-[k_3 N   +p_3 (1-N)]  -q_2 [k_2 N  + p_2 (1-N)] }
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `\mathrm{HADL}`, because I don't think it's a product of four quantities, is it? The `^{}` is meant to lower a bit the subscript.

Without `newtx` it will fit as well, but you can clearly see the font mismatch. I'll use a small trick for the second one.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:label1}
\frac{y^{}_{\mathrm{HADL}}}{x_n}=
-[k_3 N   +p_3 (1-N)]  -q_2 [k_2 N  + p_2 (1-N)]
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:label2}
\hspace{-0.5em}
\frac{x_n}{y^{}_{\mathrm{HADL}}} =
\frac{1}{-[k_3 N   +p_3 (1-N)]  -q_2 [k_2 N  + p_2 (1-N)] }
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks nice but I got this error while load `newtx` package. 
`LaTeX Error: File `newtx.sty' not found.`

Comment: I'm using overleaf.

Comment: Another question: why don't you use `x_\mathrm{n}` instead of `x_n`?

Comment: @hana Because n seems to be a math variable and not an acronym. Shouldn't it be N? For `newtx`, substitute `\usepackage{newtx}` with `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`

Comment: I see. How about subscript with number like `k_3`? Should I use `k_\mathrm{3}`?

Comment: @hana No, it's math. Use `\mathrm` for textual subscripts.

Comment: Nice to know that. I got an error  `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package textcomp` while running the code below. How can I fix it? 
https://pastebin.pl/view/9418820e

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{textcomp}`

Comment: Thanks, I promise the last question. Would all of this be compatible with IEEEtran?

Comment: @hana Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest loading `mathtools`, which is a superset of `amsmath` and use its `\splitfrac` command:

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:label1}
    \frac{x_n}{y_{HADL}} =
    -\frac{1}{\splitfrac{k_3 N +p_3 (1-N) + {}}{q_2 [k_2 N + p_2 (1-N)] }}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: another possibility would be to use the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath` (~ 80 % of \displaystyle):

```
    \begin{equation}\label{eq; label2}
      \frac{x_n}{y_{HADL}} =
    -\mfrac{1}{[k_3 N +p_3 (1-N)] + q_2 [k_2 N + p_2 (1-N)]}
    \end{equation}
```

[image]

*Still another edit*: Two other possibilities: one with the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`, which ensures equations start at the left margin, another with the `multlined` environment from `mathtools`:

```
    \begin{fleqn}
      \begin{equation}\label{eq; label2}
    \begin{split}
      \frac{x_n}{y_{HADL}} & = \\[-0.5ex]
    &\quad -\mfrac{1}{[k_3 N +p_3 (1-N)] + q_2 [k_2 N + p_2 (1-N)]}
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}
    \end{fleqn} \bigskip

      \begin{equation}\label{eq; label2}
    \begin{multlined}
      \frac{x_n}{y_{HADL}} = \\[-0.5ex]
    \quad -\mfrac{1}{[k_3 N +p_3 (1-N)] + q_2 [k_2 N + p_2 (1-N)]}
    \end{multlined}
    \end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the first one doesn't look good to me and I  worries about the second case as changing the font, size would probably violating the rules.

Comment: @hana; I've added two other possibilities.

Comment: Moving the minus sign to the begining does look better.

Answer (score 3):

If you are ok with the space, another way is to use sub-expressions with their definitions

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}   % \usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}


\begin{document}
\section{Something}
\kant[1][1]
\begin{align} \label{eq:label1}
    \frac{x_n}{y_{HADL}} &= -\frac{1}{I + q_2 J} \\
    \intertext{with}
    I &= k_3 N + p_3 (1-N), \nonumber \\
    J &= k_2 N + p_2 (1-N). \nonumber
\end{align}

\kant[1][2]
\begin{align} \label{eq:label2}
    \frac{x_n}{y_{HADL}} &= -\frac{1}{K + q_2 L} \\
    \intertext{with}
    K &= k_3 N + p_3 (1-N), \nonumber \\
    L &= k_2 N  + p_2 (1-N). \nonumber
\end{align}

\kant[1][3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a nice option as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just make it smaller to fit the page (taken from [here, example 1.1](https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook))

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:label1}
\resizebox{.4\textwidth}{!}{
$\frac{x_n}{y_{HADL}} = \frac{1}{-[k_3 N   +p_3 (1-N)]  -q_2 [k_2 N  + p_2 (1-N)]}$}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:label2}
\resizebox{.4\textwidth}{!}{
$\frac{x_n}{y_{HADL}} = \frac{1}{-[k_3 N   +p_3 (1-N)]  -q_2 [k_2 N  + p_2 (1-N)]}$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\resizebox` in this manner can lead to wildly inconsisten font sizes.